# How to send array of complex objects to another page in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

I have an array `$batchRequest` that looks like this:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  [1]=>
  object(Facebook\FacebookRequest)#18 (9) {
    ["app":protected]=>
    object(Facebook\FacebookApp)#9 (2) {
      ["id":protected]=>
      string(16) "xxxxxxx"
      ["secret":protected]=>
      string(32) "xxxxxxxx"
    }
    ["accessToken":protected]=>
    string(49) "xxxxx|xxxxxxx"
    ["method":protected]=>
    string(3) "GET"
    ["endpoint":protected]=>
    string(75) "/10209064245580796?fields=id%2Cname%2Cpicture%2Cgender%2Cfriends%2Cbirthday"
    ["headers":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["params":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["files":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["eTag":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["graphVersion":protected]=>
    string(4) "v2.5"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(Facebook\FacebookRequest)#17 (9) {
    ["app":protected]=>
    object(Facebook\FacebookApp)#9 (2) {
      ["id":protected]=>
      string(16) "xxxxx"
      ["secret":protected]=>
      string(32) "xxxxxxx"
    }
    ["accessToken":protected]=>
    string(49) "xxxx|xxxxxxxx"
    ["method":protected]=>
    string(3) "GET"
    ["endpoint":protected]=>
    string(75) "/10208823390691752?fields=id%2Cname%2Cpicture%2Cgender%2Cfriends%2Cbirthday"
    ["headers":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["params":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["files":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["eTag":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["graphVersion":protected]=>
    string(4) "v2.5"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(Facebook\FacebookRequest)#19 (9) {
    ["app":protected]=>
    object(Facebook\FacebookApp)#9 (2) {
      ["id":protected]=>
      string(16) "xxxxx"
      ["secret":protected]=>
      string(32) "xxxxxxx"
    }
    ["accessToken":protected]=>
    string(49) "xxxxx|xxxxxxx"
    ["method":protected]=>
    string(3) "GET"
    ["endpoint":protected]=>
    string(74) "/1294280923934896?fields=id%2Cname%2Cpicture%2Cgender%2Cfriends%2Cbirthday"
    ["headers":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["params":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["files":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["eTag":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["graphVersion":protected]=>
    string(4) "v2.5"
  }
  [4]=>
  object(Facebook\FacebookRequest)#20 (9) {
    ["app":protected]=>
    object(Facebook\FacebookApp)#9 (2) {
      ["id":protected]=>
      string(16) "xxxxx"
      ["secret":protected]=>
      string(32) "xxxxxxxx"
    }
    ["accessToken":protected]=>
    string(49) "xxxxx|xxxxxxxxxx"
    ["method":protected]=>
    string(3) "GET"
    ["endpoint":protected]=>
    string(74) "/1274474365912572?fields=id%2Cname%2Cpicture%2Cgender%2Cfriends%2Cbirthday"
    ["headers":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["params":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["files":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["eTag":protected]=>
    NULL
    ["graphVersion":protected]=>
    string(4) "v2.5"
  }
}
```

So its an array whose elements are complex objects. I need to send them to another page called `parallelImport.php`. Here is what I've tried:

**Using JSON**

```
$data = array('batchArrayChild' => json_encode($batchRequest), 'app_id' => $appId, 'app_secret' => $appSecret);
$endpoint_url = 'https://some-domain.net/pages/parallelImport.php';
$curl = curl_init($endpoint_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
$result = $curl_response;
print_r($result);
```

As you can see I `json_encode`ed `$batchRequest` and send it via `cURL`, and here is what it outputs:

```
string(16) "[[],{},{},{},{}]"
```

**Using http_build_query**

```
$data = array('batchArrayChild' => http_build_query($batchRequest), 'app_id' => $appId, 'app_secret' => $appSecret);
$endpoint_url = 'https://some-domain.net/pages/parallelImport.php';
$curl = curl_init($endpoint_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
$result = $curl_response;
print_r($result);
```

And after I do `var_dump($_POST['batchArrayChild'])` on parallelImport.php it says:

```
string(0) ""
```

Do you know any other way in which I could send this array to execution script and to get some kind of response?

Comment: Looks ok on first glance, so I doubt the sending is the issue. Maybe you want to dump the network traffic once to check if you really send a POST request with the content you expect. It is likely that the result you get is unexpected because that remote script does not understand the structure of the data you sent. That is nothing we can say anything about, obviously.

Comment: I logged whole `$_POST` in txt document and this - 'batchArrayChild' field is still empty.

Comment: How did you do that? "Logging into a txt document" sounds very suspicious... Then maybe you want to check first if `$data` actually contains valid `JSON` data?

Comment: I haven't tested, but will be surprised if json_encode did include any protected or private properties. It looks like everything in your classes are protected so I would expect to get empty objects from json_encode

Comment: @arkascha Yeah, you're right.. it looks like 'batchArrayChild' is empty even before sending.. Do you people know how to send this array of objects with protected values to another page?

Comment: Didn't it possible that you write this whole data to a txt file and addadded that txt file in your second file. May be that will help you. I am not sure

Comment: @Anant you mean to write this array into txt file and then to read it from parallelImport.php? Clever though

Comment: That means that `json_encode()` fails to encode the object. You never error check that. You should find out _why_ it fails to encode. Might be you have to add a `__toString()__ method...

Comment: @Ognj3n  yes the same thing. But i am not sure it's a perfect solution.BTW first take care what others are trying to point-out

Answer (score 2):

I don't like sending complex (internal) objects between systems, so I would have created a DTO (data transfer object) with public properties and used that object to send the data to avoid any coupling of objects between services. The DTO could even be of type `stdClass` if you want to make it simple.

If you want to make the services super dependent to each other including sharing state you could try to use `serialize()` on the data